# landmark deduction in media pipe with out Surface View in android

Tags: android, tensorflow, mediapipe

I am implementing media pipe hand tracking

> https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/hands

in android , able to get land mark only if camera data is previewed  else not able to deduct points

how to access the landmark with out preview of camera or image ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the VISIBILITY of the preview to GONE. In that way the preview won't show.

```
private void startCamera() {
    cameraHelper = new CameraXPreviewHelper();         
    cameraHelper.setOnCameraStartedListener(
            surfaceTexture -> {
                previewFrameTexture = surfaceTexture;
                // Make the display view visible to start showing the preview. This triggers the
                // SurfaceHolder.Callback added to (the holder of) previewDisplayView.

                // comment this *********
                // previewDisplayView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                onCameraStarted(surfaceTexture);
            });
    cameraHelper.startCamera(this, CAMERA_FACING, /*surfaceTexture=*/ null);
}
```

The "previewFrameTexture" is what is sent for processing but it is copied from the surfaceTexture. Remember this won't trigger the callback so set the converter size manually.

```
converter.setSurfaceTextureAndAttachToGLContext(previewFrameTexture,*width of your camera preview size, height of your camera preview size;
```

For more införmation check this link :
[Mediapipe Examples](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/710fb3de58dc10b7bc75f9cb758300c9016a5e4f/mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/basic/MainActivity.java#L159)